# WCF Encrypting Connection Strings with aspnet_regiis

Tags: asp.net, wcf, security

I have a WCF Service talking to a web application. In the web.config files I want to encrpyt the connetion string section.

I'm using 
`aspnet_regiis -pe "connectionStrings" -app "/WebAppFolder"`
for the web applications web.config and this works fine.

But when I do the same for the WCF service I get an internal server error when I try and connect to it via the web app.

Answer (score 1):

The problem was I needed to give my machine access to the configuration key

aspnet_regiis -pa "NetFrameworkConfigurationKey" "MYMACHINE\ASPNET"